# Unknown Location Error in a sub-module of a package I cloned from github

Tags: python, python-import

I cloned a package from github called OSSP that I need for a project I am working on. I Placed the package inside of my main source directory. I can succesfully import the packages inside of the OSSP directory. However the packages inside of the cloned OSSP package reference another sub-directory inside of itself. Everything appears to be in order. All directories aside from the root project directory contain a **init**.py file.

---

```py
from lib import utils
```

**OUT >>>** `ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from 'lib' (unknown location)`

---

**My main file (learn_gdal.py)**

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from osgeo import gdal
from pylab import newaxis
from segment import segment_image
import preprocess as pp
```

**Cloned package (inside of segment.py)**

```py
from lib import utils
```

OUT >>> `ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from 'lib' (unknown location)`

My Projects file structure is like this:

```
│   .gitignore                                                         
│   learn_gdal.png                                                     
│   learn_gdal.py                                                      
│   segment2.py                                                        
│   showsegimg2.py                                                     
│                                                                      
└───OSSP                                                               
    │   .gitignore                                                     
    │   Algorithm_Instructions.pdf                                     
    │   classify.py                                                    
    │   LICENSE                                                        
    │   ossp_process.py                                                
    │   preprocess.py                                                  
    │   readme.md                                                      
    │   segment.py                                                     
    │   setup.py                                                       
    │   training_gui.py                                                
    │   __init__.py                                                    
    │                                                                  
    ├───build                                                          
    │   └───temp.win-amd64-3.7                                         
    │       └───Release                                                
    │           └───lib                                                
    │                   attribute_calculations.cp37-win_amd64.exp      
    │                   attribute_calculations.cp37-win_amd64.lib      
    │                   attribute_calculations.obj                     
    │                   create_clsf_raster.cp37-win_amd64.exp          
    │                   create_clsf_raster.cp37-win_amd64.lib          
    │                   create_clsf_raster.obj                         
    │                   rescale_intensity.cp37-win_amd64.exp           
    │                   rescale_intensity.cp37-win_amd64.lib           
    │                   rescale_intensity.obj                          
    │                                                                  
    ├───lib                                                            
    │   │   attribute_calculations.c                                   
    │   │   attribute_calculations.cp37-win_amd64.pyd                  
    │   │   attribute_calculations.html                                
    │   │   attribute_calculations.pyx                                 
    │   │   create_clsf_raster.c                                       
    │   │   create_clsf_raster.cp37-win_amd64.pyd                      
    │   │   create_clsf_raster.pyx                                     
    │   │   debug_tools.py                                             
    │   │   rescale_intensity.c                                        
    │   │   rescale_intensity.cp37-win_amd64.pyd                       
    │   │   rescale_intensity.html                                     
    │   │   rescale_intensity.pyx                                      
    │   │   utils.py                                                   
    │   │   __init__.py                                                
    │   │                                                              
    │   └───__pycache__                                                
    │           __init__.cpython-37.pyc                                
    │                                                                  
    ├───training_datasets                                              
    │       icebridge_v5_training_data.h5                              
    │       pan_v2_training_data.h5                                    
    │       wv02_ms_v2_training_data.h5                                
    │       wv02_ms_v3.1_training_data.h5                              
    │                                                                  
    └───__pycache__                                                    
            preprocess.cpython-37.pyc                                  
            __init__.cpython-37.pyc
```

Comment: Which Python version do you use (edit: saw it: 3.7) and is there a documentation saying for which version(s) the package was written?

Comment: It was built on anaconda 3.6

Comment: It seems to me that OSSP is a standalone set of programs and not written as library. Therefore it assumes that the "OSSP" directory is included as an import root in "sys.path". A quick and dirty solution could be to add it there before importing.

Comment: I appended the OSSP directory to sys.path and appended the sub directory lib to sys.path. neither fixed or changed the problem